# Angularjs: How to display loading-icon when using 'resolve' in $routeProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following code reads via a service and shows on the web page a list of 'page' objects for a specific 'page category' (string). Using the resolve object property in $routeProvider.when(), I am able to postpone updating the view until the new value is ready.

Two questions:

1. When asking for a new page list, I want to show a loading-icon. How can I detect (in a non-hackish way) the event when the reading from server starts (and the loading-icon should be displayed)? I guess I could do something like $('.pages-loading-icon').show() in the service, but find that to be too gui dependent too placed in the service.
2. When the new value is ready, I would like the old to fade out and the new to fade in. What is the 'angular' way to do this? I have tried to do it in the controller using $watch, but that causes the new value to be display shortly before the fadeout starts.

The code:

**app.js:**

```
$routeProvider.when('/:cat', { templateUrl: 'partials/view.html', controller: RouteCtrl, resolve: RouteCtrl.resolve});
```

**controllers.js:**

```
function RouteCtrl($scope, $routeParams, pages) {
        $scope.params = $routeParams;
        $scope.pages = pages;
    }

RouteCtrl.resolve={
    pages: function($routeParams, Pages){
        if($routeParams.hasOwnProperty('cat')){
            return Pages.query($routeParams.cat);
        }
    }
}
```

**services.js:**
The last pages read is stored in currentPages and its category in lastCat.

```
factory('Pages', function($resource, $q, $timeout){
    return {
        res: $resource('jsonService/cat=:cat', {}, {
            query: {method:'GET', params:{cat:'cat'}, isArray:true}
        }),
        lastCat: null,
        currentPages: null,
        query: function(cat) {
            var res = this.res;
            if(cat != this.lastCat){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var p = res.query({'cat':cat}, function(){
                    deferred.resolve(p);
                });
                this.lastCat = cat;
                this.currentPages = deferred.promise;
            }
            return this.currentPages;
        }
    };
})
```

**view.html**

```
<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages">
        <a href="#{{params.cat}}/{{page.slug}}">{{page.title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 61):

Not exactly sure whether this would work in your code as you have $resource integration.
But it may be worth to look into angular events: `$routeChangeStart` and `$routeChangeSuccess`.

in html:

```
<span ng-show="isViewLoading"> loading the view... </span>
```

in controller (which defines the scope of the html above):

```
$scope.isViewLoading = false;
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
  $scope.isViewLoading = true;
});
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
  $scope.isViewLoading = false;
});
$scope.$on('$routeChangeError', function() {
  $scope.isViewLoading = false;
});
```

Comment: I get each event triggered twice. Maybe because I have the same controller registered for multiple routes. Will look more into this, as it sound like the way to go.

Comment: Don't forget to stop loading on `$routeChangeError`

Comment: Miss to close span
<span ng-show="isViewLoading"> loading the view... </span>

Comment: It is a nice solution, but I'm not completely happy with it. If you have links from multiple views to a "slow" view, then you have to duplicate this event handling logic in every of your views. I would like to have it in a single place, for example, in the view we navigate to. Not sure if it's possible, since the target view is only rendered after resolve.

Answer (score 4):

The routing system for angular seems to be a bit limited.. 

This solved it for me:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2420-Mapping-AngularJS-Routes-Onto-URL-Parameters-And-Client-Side-Events.htm

Also, about the events triggering twice: if you setup a route do map to "a/b/c" angular automatically sets up another route, "a/b/c/" (with trailing slash) to redirect to the first (and vice versa), and both trigger events. I just test for a presence of route parameters.

Regarding the limited condition of the routing sistem: there is [this pull](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1198) from angular, to extend it's capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the `$rootScope` because monitoring a controller's `$scope` is limited to the controller, and as it happens you're switching from one view (one controller) to another view (another controller). So it would make sense to have one-code-fit-all.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

In that function set the `$rootScope.isLoadingState` which will display your loading indicator.

Then use

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

To unset that variable.

Complete reference [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)

Answer (score 1):

I like the `'ng-show'`... But the `'ui-if'` of the Angular UI project is better IMHO.. Since remove the HTML code from the DOM...

```
<span ui-if = "isViewLoading"> loading the view... </span>
```

_e

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ng-show directive. Simply check whether you model is empty and display a DOM subset like so:

```
    <!-- model not ready -->
    <div style="width: 200" ng-show="lines == ''">
      <div class="progress progress-striped active">
         <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- your model code -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
      <li ng-repeat="line in lines">
        {{line.Id}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive that will show based on a broadcast that you send before and after a service call, which you could put on $rootScope. So if you're calling a factory to handle dishing out generic POST/GET calls then right before the call you can call a function on $rootScope, such as "$rootScope.startLoading()" and when it finishes call "$rootScope.doneLoading()", where each of these methods broadcast an event for you to pick up on your directive. Then you just handle on your directive to catch the events, "scope.$on("startLoading", func(..." and have it insert/show a loading div template into the DOM and run, then also have a catch for done loading to remove/hide it.

That way you can have a nice general loading overlay.