# Add "intermediary" page prior to full page load Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

#### My problem

I am using Angular to create a Phonegap application. Most of my pages are fairly small and the transition/responsiveness is quick and smooth. However I have one page that is fairly large that I am having an issue with.

The method for changing to this page is straightforward:

```
<button ng-click="$location.url('/page2')"></button>
```

When you "tap" the button above it takes about 1-2s to respond and change pages. I have double checked all areas for improvement on this page and determined that the delay is caused by Angular compiling and parsing the DOM of this page prior to changing the page. Please note that I am testing this on a real device so it is not due to emulator speeds.

#### The question

Is there a way to automatically or manually intercept page changes and put them in a sort of "loading" page so the response to the button click is immediate and page change is visible but the page content loads in a second or 2 later onto this "loading" page.

Its only an issue cause it is very awkward to click something and have nothing happen. I am having a very hard time finding any resources on this matter so if someone can even point me in the right direction to look I would be grateful.

**Edit:**

A super hacky solution I found was to use an ng-include on wrapper page and delay the include for a little bit.

myBigPageWrapper.html:

```
<div ng-include="page"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.page = '';
setTimeout(function() { $scope.page='/pages/myBigPage.html'; $scope.$apply(); }, 1000);
```

Then navigate to your wrapper page instead: $location.url('/myBigPageWrapper')

This is obviously not ideal... But I hope this helps clarify what I am attempting to do.

**Page2.html**

This is the section that causes the page to slow down, commenting this out makes the page load very quickly. There are 13 pages in the "auditPages" array each containing about 50 lines of html mostly containing form input elements. Quite a bit of logic however it runs great once it is loaded. I am not going to include all the pages as it would be overload.

```
<div class="page-contents">
    <form name="auditPageForm">
        <div ng-repeat="(pageKey, pageData) in auditPages " ng-show="currentAuditPage.name==pageData.name">
            <audit-form page="pageData">
                <ng-include src=" 'partials/audit/auditSections/'+pageData.name+'.html'" onload="isFormValid(pageKey)"></ng-include>
            </audit-form>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show some code of your page2 and also of your main app?

Comment: Added the main section of page2. See edit

Comment: To generate a "loading" between pages, I personnally use `$routeChangeSuccess` event (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route) on the targeted page. So no need to create an "intermediary" page, since I'm handling the "loading" code in this event. (More precisely, I start my needed `$http` call there with a loading spinner set up during the call)  This event would mean "as soon as my route is changed, what to do first?? => displaying a loading for two seconds, and then populate the whole usual content of this targeted page. Playing with ng-hide and ng-show on the template.

Comment: So, in my $routeChangeSuccess handling, I use this around my http call: https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-promise-tracker/wiki. Very handy.

Comment: @Mik378 So you just force a delay of ~2 seconds then populate your view and hide loading?

Comment: Actually, my requests are already long, so no need to add this 2 seconds, it's enough for the human eye to understand that something happens and see the loading icon. But for shorter ones yes, as the sample of the wiki of the link above shows, you can use a an additional `timeout` to keep the content hidden for 2 seconds, in case where your logic where too fast. Besides, surely this post could be interested for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352411/angularjs-how-to-display-loading-icon-when-using-resolve-in-routeprovider

Comment: @Mik378 I think I got it now, Not very happy with the timeout but it gets the job done and it seems to do it well. + Thanks on the "promise-tracker" Ill check into it more tomorrow with fresh eyes. Mind making a answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up my comments above:

Your question was:

> Is there a way to automatically or manually intercept page changes and
>   put them in a sort of "loading" page?

A lot of people asks for this question since Angular doesn't seem to provide a nice handling of a loading transition.

Indeed, the possible nicest solution would have been to "play" with the `resolve` property of angular's module configuration.
As we know, `resolve` allows to run some logic before the targeted page is rendered, dealing with a promise. The ideal would be to be able to put a loading page on this targeted page, while the `resolve` code is running.

So some people have nice ideas like this one:
[Nice way to handle loading icon while route is changing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12381623/985949) 
He uses `$routeChangeStart` event, so the loading icon would happen on the SOURCE page.
I use it and it works well.

Also, there is another way: make use of `$http` interceptor (like @oori answer above), to have a common code allowing to put a loading icon but...I imagine you don't want the same icon on every kind of http request the page does, it's up to you.

Maybe in the future, a solution would come directly associated to the `resolve` property.

Answer (score 1):

Angular has **$httpProvider.responseInterceptors**

// Original by zdam:   http://jsfiddle.net/zdam/dBR2r/

```
angular.module('LoadingService', [])
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
    var spinnerFunction = function (data, headersGetter) {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('waiting')).css('display','block');
        return data;
    };
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
}])
// register the interceptor as a service, intercepts ALL angular ajax http calls
.factory('myHttpInterceptor', ['$q','$window', function ($q, $window) {
    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(function (response) {
            angular.element(document.getElementById('waiting')).css('display','none');
            return response;

        }, function (response) {
            angular.element(document.getElementById('waiting')).css('display','none');
            return $q.reject(response);
        });
    };
}])
```

Comment: I would love to use a method like this however the problem lies with the navigation waiting for the view to be created and the scope to be applied to the dom (may not have that exactly correct, still new to Angular). I took a deep dive into responseInterceptors but from what I observed they seemed great for external calls to get data prior to rendering the view but not for rendering the view itself.

Comment: Searching/Managing DOM properties (like `getElementById`) should only do in Angular's directives. Otherwise, it goes against the essence of Angular: "we manage DOM for you".

Comment: the view **rendering** takes so long?   not the ajax requests awaiting response?     if so - this is way too long.   can you plunkr/jsfiddle it ?

Comment: I dont plan to manipulate the DOM, I plan to manipulate my variables that manipulate the DOM prior to displaying the DOM.

Comment: @Mik378,  ofcourse you're right, but that's not possible with this service.     a "little" better would be to replace *document* with *$document* injection,  but that doesn't really resolve what you meant.. I know..

Comment: @oori Unfortunately I cant and even if I could the delay is only visible on a phonegap application due to memory limitations.

Comment: @oori Here's a solution with the same concept you use, without any explicit DOM manipulation. I've just written it here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7445756.   Tip was to use `pendingRequests` method from `$http` :)