# Clear ng-view while new contents are loading?

Tags: angularjs

When I change the path of the page, my `ng-view` keeps its contents until the new ones are loaded by my `routeProvider`. Is there a way to hide them immediately and display a spinner till the new ones load?

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle regarding loading screen (can customize as necessary): http://jsfiddle.net/KmXTy/1/.

I think what you are looking for though is `ng-cloak`. It hides ng elements until Angular is ready for them.

```
<div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
<div id="template2" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">{{ 'hello IE7' }}</div>
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak.

Also, this may be helpful: [Angularjs: How to display loading-icon when using 'resolve' in $routeProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352411/angularjs-how-to-display-loading-icon-when-using-resolve-in-routeprovider).