# AngularJS Loading icon when using resolve in routeprovider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352411) question, but none of these answers seem to work. They all use the controller to show the loading icon, which if they read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), they would know that the controller isn't initialized until the request is resolved/rejected so any loading spinner coming from a controller isn't going to work.

Is it possible to show a loading spinner in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nathvarun/zRwc2/) jsfiddle so we can know that a request is in progress, instead of just leaving the page blank until it get resolved?

I would like to do something like:

```
    $routeProvider.when('/', {

        controller: 'AppCtrl',
        resolve: {
            app: function ($q, $timeout) { 
                //show a spinner
                //do something
                //no more spinner
        }
     });
```

Comment: why don't you add Loader in Interceptor so that during any server request loader will start and when server request consume then loading will be resolved.

Comment: Would it be possible to do in angularjs 1.6? I've seen some compatibility issues being reported. 

Also, you think it would access something like cg-busy to be the html loader template?

Comment: Yes it's possible AngularJs 1.6

Comment: can you provide a toy example of this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this code will useful.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {

      template: '<h1 class="panel">This is my app</h1>',
      controller: 'AppCtrl',

      resolve: {
        app: function($q, $timeout, $rootScope) {
          $rootScope.rootState.routeLoading = true;
          var defer = $q.defer();

          $timeout(function() {
            $rootScope.rootState.routeLoading = false;
            defer.resolve();
          }, 2000);
          return defer.promise;
        }
      }
    });
  })
  .controller('AppCtrl', function() {
    console.log('This is the app controller');
  })
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.rootState = {
      routeLoading: false
    }
  });
  
  angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.custom-preloader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1001;
  background-color: #999;
  display: none;
}

.custom-preloader h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.custom-preloader_visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-preloader" ng-class="{'custom-preloader_visible': rootState.routeLoading }">
  <h2>
    Loading...
  </h2>
</div>
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

Comment: This won't work if I am using template URL, and don't include a spinner into the main page?